# Simple Products not showing as associated in configurable product after reset filter

Tags: magento-1.9

I already configure all the attributes like,

```
visibilty = not show inidividually
stock = in stock
attribute set = the same as configurable product
price = also set
status = enable
```

After click on "Reset Filter" my simple products have the same attribute set are not shown...

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details about where it is not showing. Where you are using reset filter functionality. From the details you provided I am not able to get what actually your problem is.